# Restoring code from JAR

Tags: java, jar, decompiling

I accidentally deleted the whole folder nest thingy from my workspace for this project I'm working on and now I only have a exported JAR file.

Is there any way I could just open the JAR file with Eclipse or something like that?

I have tried extracting the JAR to my desktop and then just dragging the files into Eclipse but it doesn't work. It just gives me all the classes back but I cannot use them.

Is there any way I can get the code from the JAR file?

Comment: Sounds like you want a [Java Decompiler](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+decompiler), and no, it probably won't be too 
easy. Trying to recover it with something like [Undelete Plus](http://undeleteplus.com/) may be a simpler option.

Comment: Did you delete it from your hard drive or from eclipse. Sometimes eclipse does not delete it from your disk.

Answer (score 3):

you definitely need a java decompiler like :

http://java.decompiler.free.fr/

download jd-gui and open your jar with this program and then "save all sources" to someplace.

Comment: Thanks I used it, but it kinda f*cked up (sorry) my code now it doesnt even want to run anymore