# Create project from .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I will explain what I need to do, in fact I found this answer [Restoring code from JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345118/restoring-code-from-jar) which is pretty close to my needs but with a key difference.

What I have is a folder with many jar files which include the .class but also the .java files of an application, I would like to restore the project into any IDE such as Eclipse or netbeans.

In order to make it clearer, the structure of what I have is the following:

- Main_directory

  - File_1.jar

    - file_1_1.java
    - file_1_1.class
    - file_1_2.java
    - file_1_2.class
  - File_2.jar

    - file_2_1.java
    - file_2_1.class
    - file_2_2.java
    - file_2_2.class

I would really appreciate any suggestions but I would like to avoid using decompilers.

Best.-

Comment: you can take out tje java files and put them to a new project to the right directories, if it isnt too big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.jar files can be opened and files extracted with many programs, such as tar, winrar, etc.  Your best bet, considering these .jar files contain the actual .java files is to extract them with such a tool, create a new project in your ide(eclipse) and then import the .java files to the new project.

Comment: Thanks Ryhnn! I did as you suggested, in fact I used the command jar -xvf fileName.jar and then I exported the content of the decompressed file into a new Java project into Eclipse.