# Restoring Eclipse Project From Jar

Tags: java, eclipse

Unfortunately, I've deleted a major project I was working on in Eclipse, but I did have a .jar file from a previous build lying around, so I decompiled this using JD-GUI, and now I'm stuck with a NewSkills.src folder filled with .java files.

How can I put this back into my eclipse project, so that I can edit it once again and continue on my project?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995283/create-project-from-jar-file

Comment: @suninsky Yeah, I actually did notice that post, but what option do I select for the importing?

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670227/decompile-a-java-project-and-compile/23670621#23670621

Answer (score 0):

U could just move the file to ur eclipse workspace and if that doesn't work there should be a way to create a new project from existing file.